# How do i get ctrlpbuftag to work?

Tags: vim, ctrlp

So I've been experimenting with Vim, switching over from Sublime. I wanted a feature in vim similar to that of `ctrl R` in Sublime, which would show me a list of functions in the current document, and narrow it down as I keep typing. [Sublime code-like method browser in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693020/sublime-code-like-method-browser-in-vim) has the answer to the same. But I've done all the steps mentioned there, including installing the `CtrlP` plugin, installing and setting up `ctags`, adding the shortcut in `.vimrc` file, but when I use the shortcut, it gives me a "NO ENTRIES". I'm editing on scala.

Comment: Could you give the corresponding part of your vimrc? And have you checked that the ctags output file is what you expect?

Comment: Why do you want a plugin for that when you can do `:g/def/#`, or `:il def`, or maybe even `:dli /` if `define` is set correctly?

Answer (score 12):

If this feature is not working after installing CtrlP you may have the following issues :

*Missing ctags :*

1. Linux : `sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags`
2. Mac : `brew install ctags`
3. Windows :

   1. Download *CTAGS* from [sourceforce](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ctags/files/ctags/5.8/ctags58.zip/download?use_mirror=iweb)
   2. Add it to your PATH variable
   3. Follow my second solution

*CtrlPBufTag is not enabled :*

Since `:CtrlPBugTag` is considered a plugin you may need to enable it in your `.vimrc` file :

```
let g:ctrlp_extensions = ['buffertag']
```